# In Ruby do single quotes need to be escaped in double quoted strings?

Tags: ruby, string, quotes

Say I have the following double-quoted string in Ruby:

```
"Person's name"
```

**Does the single quote need to be escaped?**

Comment: Why not try it in `irb`?

Comment: I did try in irb. Both "Person's name" and "Person\'s name" worked so I wasn't sure.

Comment: Wouldn't you then conclude that it wasn't required?

Comment: Man whenever I ask questions like this, I get like 5 down votes..  Sigh.

Comment: @MarkThomas perhaps :-)  Although asking often helps learn something new or interesting.

Comment: To all the "why didn't you just try it?" people: there is a big difference between specified/required behavior and accidental behavior. And it is very easy to get trapped in special cases when you "just try it".

Comment: But the questioner could mention, that he already tried it, but is not sure about his/her conlusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test and the aother answers showed you already, that there is no difference.

```
p "Person's name"
p "Person\'s name"
```

With single quotes, it is a difference:

You get a syntax error with

```
p 'Person's name'
```

The quoted version will work:

```
p 'Person\'s name'
```

If this behaviour irritated you, perhaps you prefer another possibility to create a String:

```
p %{Person's name}
p %q{Person's name} #like '
p %Q{Person's name} #like "
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

But wouldn't just running it have answered that?

Answer (score 1):

The reverse holds true too.  If I know i'm going to be using double quotes, i'll use single quotes to wrap my string in.  However, it may be best to use double quotes at all times , if you use other languages, since single quotes usually just reference a character.  It gets annoying modifying my c# code because I said var x = 'hello world';